# C++ @ custom annotation as Java or Python

Tags: java, c++, rest, annotations, web-frameworks

It's possible to create a custom annotation like `@` or another character as Rust's [#...] in C++?

Target would be something like:

```
#pragma once

#include "my_header.h"

@RestController(path = "/home")
void MyClass::some_method(int int_arg)
{
    // some C++ code
}
```

I've already been reading old similar questions to this, but like 7 or more years old from now.

There is a way to achieve this these days?

Regards

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes. It depends what exactly you're looking for out of it though.

Comment: No @chris, it's not posible to create custom ones, which are the point of the topic

```
The compiler ignores any attributes that it doesn't recognize, which means you can't define your own custom attributes using this syntax
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=msvc-170

Comment: The compiler ignores them, but tools are free to use them. The language doesn't (currently) give you a way to programmatically interact with attributes, so whether or not the compiler ignores them is irrelevant. That's why it depends on whether, say, a precompilation step is good enough or whether you were specifically looking for something that can generate code or do another task as part of compilation itself.

Comment: To be clear, you can absolutely have a custom attribute in the sense of `[[my::RestController(path = "/home")]]` that a tool does something special with, you just don't (currently) get access to that kind of power in the code itself during compilation. For some people and use cases, that's enough, but it wasn't clear from the question text whether that was the case here.

Comment: You're absolutly right @chris
I am trying to desing a web framework (just for learning purposes) in the Spring's style. 
The idea it's to make available the content of the annotated thinks to another internal classes. I've seen another wonderful C++ projects in this style already, but I wanted to plan it as a DI container, where you can "register" your classes and make it available to the end user thought several API's.
Can you further explain if there is an option to retrieve the value of the path's `[[my::RestController(path = "/home")]]` attribute? Or there is no way even in C++20?

Comment: There's nothing at all that your code can query about attributes right now, not even their presence. There are definitely people who _want_ reflection to include attributes and their contents, but even that would be a ways off as well as breaking the notion that ignoring an attribute doesn't change the code's meaning. I get the appeal of annotation-based generation having used it myself elsewhere, but it's going to be quite some time, if ever, until C++ mimics that.

Comment: What w'd be the best C++ approach nowadays? I guess that with C++ macros could achieve something si millar (at least in terms of make It available to some sort of DI container)

Comment: I think macros are the most common solution for a more direct translation of things like this. I'd suggest looking into a variety of existing DI, server-side REST, etc. libraries out there to get a feel for all the paths people have taken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

As a general concept there's nothing similar. I'd venture it requires run-time type information which would increase binary size for lots of use-cases and be too easy to break unless you're super careful with the language.

There's something in the works (compile-time reflection) which will be really powerful (all of the benefits, with none of the downsides at run-time). AFAIK, at the time of writing it's still a proposal and I can't find anything on the progress.

Last, I'd like to point out that if you try to write Java or Rust in C++, you're going to have a bad time. There are solutions in C++ for most problems, but might look slightly differently and have different characteristics (performance, drawbacks, etc).

I don't see why you can't define a static registration function that gives you the same functionality. There's already a ton of things you can do between macros and templates, but I would suggest asking a more focused question on that.

Comment: Because it would be a nice addition to the language in terms of, for example, build web API's in a modern approach.

But can you elaborate something similar with the template mechanism? I mean, it's my first idea out of the annotation one, but I am just wondering that w'd be something nice in addition.

Comment: @Pyzyryab If you want the self registration part, I haven't implemented one myself, but I've seen them used a ton in test libs. Here's one: https://blog.rubenwardy.com/2019/02/17/cpp-self-registering-test-macros/. For named parameters (I guess you want them mapped to the URL params), I've seen something like this: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/12/02/named-arguments/ but would probably require more work to make it integrate nicer with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Pyzyryab maybe even easier would be for the function to take a class you can already serialize and/or reflect on (like https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial ) then the mapping to/from the URL should be simpler.

Comment: I've really liked the second approach @Sorin but as you mentioned, I am founding difficult to think about how to integrate it with the code. 
The attributes written there must be abailable to some sort of DI container... it's still a very early stage of an idea (neither a project) but I guess there will be some class as the Spring's Rest Template that coud map all these attributes into a kind of router